# HttpRetryExcepiton while trying to send gcm message

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm getting a java.net.HttpRetryException exception when attempting to send a message to GCM server from my server.

```
try {
    multiResult = sender.send(message, devices, RETRY_COUNT);
} catch(IOException e) {
    logger.error("{0}\t- ANDROID : IOException occured during sending message: {1}", e.getMessage());

}
```

I have succesfully registered devices, but this send method gives me exception as shown below

```
java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:362)
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:261)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i find the reason, i was trying to send the notification with the wrong apikey, which is an android key, Google says it should be a server key (a browser key also works)

Answer (score 0):

You're right but browser key won't work as I tried, so if any one getting this error just try to re-generate the api key (which is server key only not browser or android key) that we generate by selection public api access from google api console.

Comment: i am re-generate the API key(server key) but its show same exception please help that as soon as possible

Comment: just post ur exception !

Comment: java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication